# Parse SQL output from another command

Tags: mysql, powershell, plesk

I am trying to parse SQL output from a command, it doesn't and cannot connect using a native library like the MySQL .Net Connector, but the output is 'the same'. Is there any way to parse its output into a table, and search the rows etc, like I was using the connector?

```
PS> plesk db "SELECT d.name,h.php_handler_id FROM domains d JOIN hosting h ON h.dom_id=d.id WHERE h.php_handler_id NOT LIKE '%fastcgi-5.6%' OR '%fastcgi-7%';"
+-----------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| name                                                | php_handler_id |
+-----------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| cms.123.com                                         | cgi-           |
| 99923.com                                           | cgi-           |
| cms4.123.com                                        | cgi-4          |
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I can then use the name/handler variables and print them.

Comment: Well, the result can be parsed, but that'll be a lot of work. Why can't you connect to the database directly?

Comment: Unfortunately its a limitation of the system

Comment: I don't understand the limitation... Plesk just runs with a MySQL back-end... have you _tried_ aacccessing it with the .NET connector?

Comment: e.g. https://talk.plesk.com/threads/connect-to-database-with-net.345831/

Comment: Hi,  we cannot pass the plesk admin password which is needed to connect using the mysql connector, hence the need to do it this way. If it was possible then I would have done that first. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`plesk` utility documentation](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/cli-linux/plesk-utility.75661/):

> `db` and `db dump` commands can be followed by mysql and mysqldump options respectively:

The `mysql` command has a parameter `-B` that generates tab-separated output instead of tabular output, so you should be able to do something like this:

```
$result = plesk db -B "SELECT ..." | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t"
```

Comment: I genuinely tried this, but seems I had something wrong in my syntax...thankyou :)